# Do I need to check if record exist in a belongs_to association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This might be a silly question, but I would like to know if it's a good practice to test if a record exists, even when is a 'belongs_to' association?

For example:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :book

   def my_method
      if self.book.present? # <- Do I need this?
         # Do Something
      end
   end
end
```

What do you guys think? What about when belongs_to :book, optional: true?

Comment: As of Rails 5 the `belongs_to` relationship is required by default. You can opt out by addition `optional: true` but if you do not you will not be able to save a `MyModel` where the `book_id` does not exist so this check would be superfluous

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if having the book is mandatory then obviously you don't need to check for the existence of the association. But if it is not it is a good practice to check or else it might throw an exception when you try to fetch any attribute or make any change on the association. With mandatory I mean this validation:

```
validates :book, presence: true
```

Or having a `NOT NULL` constraint on the database column or having:

```
belongs_to :book
```

without `optional: true`

Also instead of `self.book.present?` you could check `book_id.present?` or `book.present?`. Two things here:

1. `self` is redundant, it is not required
2. If you just want to check the association exists or not and don't want to load that from the database you could check `book_id.present`

Comment: Thank you Deepesh, it's an excelent answer. I tried here, 'book_id.present?' works fine, and it's a good idea to not load from the database. The book.present? returns nil when I don't add self.book. I don't know exactly the reason, but I just got that.

Comment: Where are you calling that method?

Comment: As far as I know the `self.book` is mandatory when you are assigning some value to it like `self.book = Book.find(1)`. For fetching the value it is not required as Ruby calls all the methods on `self` automatically.

Comment: I need to update an attribute from book. For example
`book.update(title: 'title')`
I will receive a 500 if book is nil.